# How can I make a table—or something table-like—flow across CSS 3 columns?

Tags: html, css

I'm laying out a book excerpt that has a lot of text and a lot of tables—baseball leaderboards—flowing across multiple CSS 3 columns with no fixed height. This one in particular is a long, narrow list of Gold Glove winners. But when I format the baseball data in tables, it doesn't break itself up into columns, so I just get one long table.

That is, with the text-heavy "pages" I've been doing something like this and then pasting in 500 words from the excerpt, which has worked well—

```
-webkit-column-width: 205px;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
```

With the tables I'd like to have it behave according to something like this:

```
-webkit-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-gap: 20px;
```

How can I make tabular data play nicely with these columns? Is my best option to make something table-like out of DIVs?

Comment: tabular data === tables  doesn't format itself into columns? not sure how you are trying to format it or with what...but you can always manually copy/paste table elements, like thead, th, tbody, tr, td, etc.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in [a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)? I can't visualise the problem from your description... =/

Answer (score 0):

You'll essentially need to remove the table display from the elements and turn each row into something with `display:block;` and each cell of the 'table' have `display:inline-block;` and the desired width. You could in theory do this with CSS on your current table so it degrades nicely, or you could use `<div>`s with `<span>`s or something like that. Either way, you need to break the table from its current display mode to something where each row is its own block element.

**Example:**

```
table { display:block; }
tr { display:block; }
td { display:inline-block; }
    td.short { width:100px; }
    td. [etc...]
```